# I'd like to Insert markup into search results with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, search, sphinx, ads

i'm after suggestions. Here's what i'm trying to do.

I'm using Rails with Thinking Sphinx to search my Database of Books. A bit like this:

```
results = Books.search 'blabla' :where => {:author => author_id}
```

Which works fine and resturns me an array of results. I then loop over each result and display book information back in a pretty grid. Lovely Jubly.

However, because I eventually want my website to make money i'm selling advertising on this site and ideally i'd like the ads to be positioned within the same grid as the results, after say every 5 results i'd like to show an advert.

I've racked my little brain but cannot think of a simple way to do this. So I thought i'd ask you clever people.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: `.each_slice(x)` will "slice" your collection every `x` elements: `@products.each_slice(5) do |five_products_array|`. Use it to insert the ad inside (you could use a random integer between 6 and 3 instead of 5).

Comment: Thank you. each_slice sounds perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view you could use `elements.each_slice(4) do | batch |` on your result set to break it up.

Ex:

```
elements.each_slice(4) do | batch |
    batch.each do |b|
        #print out the first batch
        #then print out your ad or whatever it is you want
    end
end
```

Comment: each_slice looks to do just what i'm looking for. Thank you. I'll have a good read through the API and let you know if I have any more questions.